# Are Clifford groups very *non-commutative*?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra

[Clifford groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra#Clifford_group) seem to be very non-commutative by the relation \begin{equation}
\gamma_{i}\gamma_{j}=-\gamma_{j}\gamma_{i}.
\end{equation} But is it really so? Can we put this *degree of non-commutative* in a precise form?

I tried the standard, namely, the commutator\begin{equation}
[Cl(n),Cl(n)]=\{\pm1\},
\end{equation} where $Cl(n)$ is the Clifford group of degree $n$. From this it seems Clifford groups are not really that bad for the commutator is rather small.

However the centre $Z(Cl(n))$ is $\{\pm 1\}$ for even $n$ and $\{\pm 1, \pm\gamma_{1}\gamma_{2}\cdots\gamma_{n}\}$ for odd $n$, which seems also small.

So my question consists of two parts: **1. Are Clifford groups very non-commutative?** and **2. Are there some convenient/ strong indicators of the degree of non-commutativeness?**

I am actually more interested in the second, and have some rather naive thoughts: Maybe the degrees of irreducible representation of $G$,
$\{\operatorname{degree}(\alpha):\alpha\in\hat{G}\}$, would contain some hints. Firstly, $\#\{\operatorname{degree}(\alpha)=1\}=\#G/[G,G]$;secondly, $\operatorname{degree}_{\alpha}|\#G/Z(G)$; last but not least, non-commutative can be thought of as a high dimensional phenomena since 1-by-1 matrices are commutative in multiplication.

Again these are just naive thoughts and I would like to hear your opinion on the *degree of non-commutativeness*. Thanks very much!

(**Well,** actually this is what truly motivates this question: assume $\#\{\operatorname{degree}(\alpha)=1\}$ and $max_{\alpha}\operatorname{degree}(\alpha)$ or $gcd(\operatorname{degree}(\alpha))$ give some information on the commutativity, then what do things like $\#\{\operatorname{degree}(\alpha)=n\}$ tell us? Higher dimensional commutativity?)

Comment: A link to a definition of Clifford groups would not hurt!

Comment: I'm not sure the degree of non-commutativity can be easily quantified, although the centre and the commutator seem like sensible things to think about. I actually think of anti-commutativity (and more generally quasi-commutativity) as being very close to genuine commutativity.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I understand that... But I cannot really find a direct definition of Clifford groups. I learnt about them from Barry Simon's book on representations of finite and compact groups. The definition there is in Chp 4. It is very clear but rather tedious to write out.

Comment: @MattPressland After some thought anti-commutativity does behave like commutativity, but, well, it is just a feeling...

Comment: @HuiYu Indeed - I don't know how to make it more precise. (I'm not even sure that there's any reason to make it more precise,but maybe something interesting could come of thinking about this).

Comment: For a definition of Clifford group, does http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra#Clifford_group suffice?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thanks! I will just put the link in. But I found this definition rather complicated, at least not as direct as the one given in Barry Simon's book. That is why I did not give the link in the first place.

Comment: To be honest, looking at that wiki article, it's not clear to me what $\alpha$ is supposed to represent save for maybe some kind of reversion operation. Still, it sounds like the elements of the group are invertible elements of the algebra that underlie orthogonal transformations. Dorst, Fontijne, and Mann call such objects *versors*.

Comment: If I got it right, the group of units of the Clifford algebra that you describe is a $2$-group. Hence it is nilpotent, so in a sense "next to being commutative".

Comment: @Muphrid If you scroll up a little, you can see that person defined $\alpha$ to be the extension map of $x\mapsto -x$.

Comment: See also the discussion on MO: [Measures of non-abelian-ness](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/125501/)

Comment: There seems to be several objects called *Clifford group*. I am fairly sure that this asker is interested in a 2-group defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3212988/11619). The definition in WP that @HaraldHanche-Olsen linked to is that of a Lie group, a very different beast. It seems to me that quantum computing enthusiasts use yet another definition. Alas, I don't have the expertise to sort this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can always find $g$ such that $ab=gba$. (Namely, $g=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, the commutator) When $g$ is the identity $1$, you have commutativity, and when your group has a fellow like $-1$, you get anticommutativity.

Really, then, it looks like you would like to measure how "big" $g$ is, where $1$ is considered small. Even $-1$ might not really be considered "small", even if it is in the "wrong direction(?)". Potentially there is some valuation which says when things are "far from 1". Really, commutativity an anticommutativity are both not very pathological.

Comment: Do you mean $ab = gba$ so $g = [a,b]$?

Comment: @m.k. Yeah! Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Some random thoughts:  The lack of normal subgroups can be considered a measure of noncommutativity.  If you divide $Cl(n)$ by its center, you get $O(n)$.  The connected component is the group $SO(n)$ which is simple (has no non-trivial connected normal sungroups) for $n\ne 4$.  There is a very nice criteria for when a Lie group is semi-simple (direct product of simple groups).  This is the non-degeneracy of the Killing form, which is a bilinear form on the Lie algebra.  On the other extreme, the Killing form of an abelian Lie group is zero.  So you can think of the number of non-degenerate directions of the Killing form as a measure of noncommutativity.

Comment: @rejected-edit: If you have any comments about the *content* of an answer, please leave a comment instead of editing the answer.

Comment: Although I do not quite know Killing forms, the lack of normal subgroups is definitely a good place to start for measuring non-commutativity. One step further, we might look at the lack of epimorphisms from $G$ is the category $\operatorname{Grp}$.

Answer (score 0):

The center is a measure of commutativity or its lack, namely a commutative group G has Z(G) = G and if Z(G) is a proper subgroup of G , any x not in Z(G) fails to commute with at least one element in G. The commutator is a tougher
subgroup  to use although [G,G] = (1) iff G is commutative.

Comment: $Z(G)$ and $[G,G]$ are dual objects inside the same group. So I guess we cannot really say one is tougher than another.