# Natural irreducible modules over Clifford algebras?

Tags: representation-theory, clifford-algebras

Let $V$ be a complex vector space with a nondegenerate quadratic form $\langle -, -\rangle$. Let $\mathrm{Cl}(V)$ be the Clifford algebra: the quotient of the tensor algebra $\mathrm{T}(V)$ by the relations $v \otimes v = \langle v, v \rangle 1$.

If $V$ is even dimensional, say $\dim(V) = 2k$, I have read that $\mathrm{Cl}(V)$ has a unique (up to isomorphism) irreducible representation $S$ of rank $2^k$, and an algebra isomorphism $\mathrm{Cl}(V) \cong \mathrm{End}_\mathbb{C}(S)$, basically a matrix algebra. If $V$ is odd-dimensional, say of dimension $2k+1$, instead $\mathrm{Cl}(V) \cong \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(S) \oplus \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(S)$, so $S$ arises in two different non-isomorphic ways.

Is there a coordinate-free definition of the $2^k$-dimensional irreducible representation $S$ of $\mathrm{CL}(V)$? Something expressed directly in terms of tensor operations and the quadratic form?

Each source I have looked at (including previous math.SE questions) either omits/glosses over the construction of this representation, or else uses a choice of basis and explicit coordinates thereafter (making it hard for me to tell what parts are natural, if any). That said, I wouldn't be surprised if I'm just overlooking something – if so, a link would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have a vague recollection of this being related to the representation theory of [this variant of a Clifford group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3212988/11619). The irreducible representations of a 2-group have dimensions that are powers of two.

Comment: Why do you think a coordinate-free definition exists? Just because its unique up to isomorphism doesn't mean its coordinate-free/natural. The [gamma matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices) give a representation of $\mathrm{Cl}_4(\mathbb C)$, but they can represent **any** orthonormal vector basis.